# LinearLayouts on top of each other

Tags: android

I'm must getting started with android app development.  I'm using Android Studio and working through the tutorial.  I keep having 2 elements lay on top of each other, whereas one should be below the first element.  It is probably a very noob mistake, but hey, I'm a noob and I don't know what it is.  :)  Code follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="org.kehrli.testapp.MyActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/enter_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is a LinearLayout , you must specify `android:orientation`, that says whether the child elements should stack `horizontal` or `vertical`.

Since you want to stack vertically, update the `android:orientation` value to `vertical`.

Answer (score 0):

Your linear layout orientation is set to `horizontal`, make it `vertical` and you should be seeing them one below the other.

Change `android:orientation="horizontal"`
to `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a CoordinatorLayout, you want your ToolBar inside an AppBarLayout instead of a LinearLayout. A bit like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

You should checkout the [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) for more information on the scroll flags, etc.

In addition the 2nd linear layout may need a layout behavior so it sits below the app bar. So if you see that you may need to add this attribute:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```